# How to reset (as it resets when pushed button on computer case) or immediately turn off PC (as if unplugged from power grid) from Windows?

Tags: windows

I want to immediately reset (as it resets when I push reset button on computer case) or immediately turn off PC (as if unplugged from power grid) but with some method inside Windows. Maybe I can kill any Windows process or or make something inside Windows that it immediately resets or turns off? Any software solutions are welcome. There is no problem if I lost data or even make hardware unusable (better if no harm to hardware but it is solution too).

Please no any hardware solutions. Also no BSOD or any kind of freezes, I need PC to immediately reset or make it immediately off.

That can be useful in situations when you are working with encrypted HDD and you want to immediately restart or turn off.

Comment: I think @Sebi answer will be the closest you get to a immediate shutdown. There will be not enough time to open a command prompt and run `shutdown /a` to abort the process.

Comment: This is either a windows scripting question (off-topic) or a request for a product (off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file:

**shutdown.bat**

```
@echo off
shutdown.exe /r /t 00
```

and then create [hotkeys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-keyboard-shortcuts-open-programs) to run it.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I need "immediately reset (as it resets when I push reset button on computer case) or immediately turn off PC (as if unplugged from power grid)". For example, when I run your example there was messege on the screen which asked to cancel restart because some application is not responding. I am pretty sure there can be also other solutions to stop restart or shutdown. So shutdown and restart are are not a solution.

Comment: try `/f` in Windows 10